# React Native: what lifecycle should I look for when I want to refresh ListView whenever I navigate back to it?

Tags: facebook, callback, react-native, react-native-listview

Pretty much like the official tutorial here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html:

I have the `fetchData` method called in `ComponentDidMount`, but according to [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html), `ComponentDidMount`would only be called once after initial rendering of the component. So should I do call the same `fetchData` everytime before I navigate back to this ListView, and pass the updated data as props to the ListView, and then update the listView's state parameter accordingly in `componentDidUpdate`? Or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Seems redux is promising, wonder if there's good tutorials that comes with react native.

Answer (score 0):

You should register an event listener on componentDidMount and unregister it on componentWillUnmout, and emit events whenever and wherever you change the data your component displays.

Good rundown of this pattern here: https://colinramsay.co.uk/2015/07/04/react-native-eventemitters.html